# Allowing content access only though aliases and views

Tags: nodes, 8, path-aliases

I'm building a site in Drupal 8 that will have complex content best viewed using views. The basic pages should use nice and clean URL aliases.

Is there a way to stop the visitor from accidentally using **/node/x** in the URL and only allow accessing the views and pages that have aliases and organised in the website menus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in Drupal 7 this functionality was covered under the [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module. It has since been merged in the Drupal 8 version of [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect).

Under the Redirect settings (**/admin/config/search/redirect/settings**), the **Global Redirect** section contains options to enable alias, non-clean, & canonical redirecting. This will enable you to redirect any requests from **/index.php?q=node/X** or **/node/X** to **/my-canonical-content-alias**.